# Accessing SQL Server from Batch File - not connecting

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sql-server-2012

I am attempting to execute queries to a SQL Server from a batch file. At a later date, I will be using the batch file to send parameters to these queries, but for now, I am just trying to use a batch file to execute.

The batch file looks like this:

```
sqlcmd -S "servername"\"dbname" -i "query.sql"
```

And the error message I am getting is this:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : SQL Server Network Inte
>   rfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. .
>   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Login timeout expired.
>   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : A network-related or in
>   stance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server
>   . Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and i
>   f SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see
>    SQL Server Books Online..

I am certain that I have the instance name of the server correct, and I know that the server has remote connection enabled. My machine is on the same network as the server, and the server responds when I query it through SSMS. I have tried connecting with my admin username and password, but that makes no difference.

Edit: As RBarryYoung pointed out, I confused instance names with database names.

Comment: pretty sure that's not the right format for specifying the dbname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
sqlcmd -S "servername\instancename" -d "dbname" -i "query.sql" -E
```

Also, it looks like you are confusing Instance names with Database names, so you need to be sure which is which in your SQL Server.

Comment: That did it, thanks a ton. I misunderstood what `-S` did